# How to fix Issue with convert Base64 to byte from GPS & Fingerprint data compare?

Tags: c#, hex, base64, arrays, fingerprint

I am trying to compare Finger print string & GPS data by converting byte array but result are not working for same finger record from different ends.

Here is my string/hex values from finger scan device & GPS accordingly. 
Finger print encoded result as below.

```
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
```

GPS Tracker sending in HEX Code as below

```
03 01 5A 16 96 00 FF FE E0 02 C0 00 80 00 80 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 32 0B 16 9E 59 91 03 FE 6D 15 1A BE 55 98 85 7E 5D 9E 5B 7E 3A A5 0E 1E 16 2C 8C BE 25 B2 8B 1E 1E 0D 95 5F 75 9A C6 B7 24 23 8E BF 70 A3 87 7F 3B AE 49 FF 16 B7 8B DF 36 91 00 1C 41 14 56 FC 3D 91 16 9A 37 9D 14 F8 33 1F 92 19 30 16 2C 56 24 1C 12 36 2C 17 55 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

How to compare both with byte array??
Finger print code required to Convert FromBase64 string to Byte and GPS code required to Hex to byte..
I am getting different array size from Finger print it returning 512 byte array and from GPS it comes 256 byte array..

below is my code form C#
Create demo aspx page and check it.

I have added Demo project here.
you can download and check it..
http://maplayout.com/demo.zip

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been resolved issue by converting HEX Code string to Byte[] and 
USB reader value convert fromBase64 string then Byte[]

I have created below method to Compare both with byte[], 
below fpengine is the thirdparty COM Object that will use for compare finger scanned value with finger point algorithm.

```
 public bool IsMatchFound(string HexCodeString , string USBReaderString)
        {
            try
            {
                int scope = 0, intdisc=0;
                byte[] gmat = HexEncoding.GetBytes(HexCodeString, out intdisc); //StringToByteArray(str1);
                byte[] gref = Convert.FromBase64String(USBReaderString);
                scope = fpengine.MatchTemplate(gmat, gref);

                return (scope > 30) ? true : false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Let me know if anybody want help same kind of application..